# How does Superman know Batman is Bruce Wayne

Tags: plot-explanation, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

In the final fight between Batman and Superman in *Batman V Superman: Dawn of Justice*, Superman addressed Batman as Bruce which is his true identity. How did he know Batman was Bruce Wayne?

Comment: ...He can see through his suit? ;)

Comment: Yes Superman has x-ray vision but bone structure  is not enough

Comment: I don't think it's *really* x-ray, though... That's just the term coined for his ability to see through solid objects. I think his vision works differently than regular x-ray and he can fine-tune it to see whatever he likes. He *is* an alien, after all.

Comment: He also caught on at the party.

Comment: Well superman does have x-Ray vision. Pretty sure he could see under batmans suit.

Comment: Christopher Reeve's Superman was able to tell the color of Lois's panties once she moved away from the lead lined planter.

Comment: I think Superman developed his vision ability to see what he wants to see. So, I believe he can probe the clothes for body or bone..

Comment: Imagine if it was pure x-ray, he would do radiation damage to everyone he sees thru  hahaha

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's strongly implied when Clark/Superman can hear Alfred talking to Bruce during Lex Luthor's party (when Bruce starts snooping around so he can hack into LexCorp's mainframe) that he is realizing that Bruce Wayne is Batman.

Also I would venture to say their conversation at the same party suggests that both are on to each other about the other's identity (as evidenced by the direct question from Clark to Bruce about Batman, and Bruce mocking the Daily Planet's love for Superman).

I don't believe there's any explicit evidence in the film, just suggestions.  That said, if everything in a movie is explicitly stated, that kind of takes some of the fun of interpretation out, right?

Comment: But I still feel that Bruce has no clue and still has no clue that Clark Kent is Superman, but your theory make sense

Comment: @war_Hero i wouldn't doubt that.  You could argue that Bruce not knowing what Superman meant when he said "Martha" indicates he didn't know Clark was Superman, as you think a guy like Bruce would have researched the Clark a bit if he knew who he really was.

Comment: @war_Hero: The WB cartoons handled this neatly in the Batman-Superman special in the late 90's. Superman simply used the X-ray vision to learn who Batman was. Later on, when Superman is in his apartment, undressing to turn in for the night, he finds a small bat-shaped transmitter stuck to his cape. He looks out the window, and using his super-vision he sees Batman a half mile or so away, looking at him. After a moment Batman gives him a thumbs-up and departs.

Answer (score 1):

It's not explicitly stated in the film but it can be speculated that he got it in the party.

He heard him talking to Alfred and maybe by the conversation he made his speculation about his secret identity. He even stopped him from stealing Kryptonite, so he might have done all his research from the time of party to this point of time. And it was no tough for him with his super-hearing.

Comment: even with that there are a ton of loopholes, how did superman know about white portuguese

Comment: @war_Hero I do feel film was too rushed for small details.

Comment: If Supes listened hard enough, he could probably hear the Bat-computer's cooling fans.

Answer (score -2):

I think it is a bit like the video game Batman: Arkham Knight. After you rescue Jim Gordon, he somehow knows Batman's true identity, You never figure out how he knew but, there was evidence of Batman talking to Alfred, and just like the party scene in BVS Clark knows about Batman's identity by just doing the simple and putting two and two together.